# Pyaudio - I can't record more than 10 seconds.What could be the issue?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, portaudio

I'm developing a screen recorder with Tkinter and Pyaudio but i'm encountering some issues:I can not record more than 10 seconds.For example if i try to record 1 minute of video, i can only get 10 seconds.
I'll leave my code down bellow.I didn't saw any errors in the command line.I made comments in my code so that you can understand what is happening:

```
"""
    recordFile.py records audio from the default microphone in a background 
    thread using pyaudio.
"""

import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess
from tkinter import messagebox

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5


# WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp/tmp.wav"

class recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False  # is the process running?
        self.process = None  # stores a reference to the background thread
        self.filename = ""  # the name of the file to record to
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.devices = [None]
        self.error = False

    def record(self, filename):
        # end the process before starting a new one
        if self.process and self.process.is_alive():
            self.going = False
        self.error = False

        # start a recording thread
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename

    def _record(self):
        try:
            # initialize pyaudio
            streams = []
            frames = []  # stores audio data
            for i in range(len(self.devices)):
                streams.append(self.p.open(format=FORMAT,
                                           channels=CHANNELS,
                                           rate=RATE,
                                           input=True,
                                           frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                                           input_device_index=self.devices[i]))
                frames.append([])

            print("* recording")

            self.going = True  # let the system know that we are running

            while self.going:  # stream the audio into "frames"
                for i in range(len(self.devices)):
                    data = streams[i].read(CHUNK)
                    frames[i].append(data)

            print("* done recording")

            # stop recording
            for i in range(len(self.devices)):
                streams[i].stop_stream()
                streams[i].close()

            # write the audio data to a file (tmp/tmp.wav)
            for i in range(len(self.devices)):
                wf = wave.open(
                    self.filename[:self.filename.find(".")] + "_" + str(i) + self.filename[self.filename.find("."):],
                    'wb')
                wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
                wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
                wf.setframerate(RATE)
                wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames[i]))
                wf.close()
        except Exception as e:
            self.error = True
            messagebox.showerror("AUDIO ERROR", "ERROR ENCOUNTERED RECORDING AUDIO: " + str(e))

    def getDeviceCount(self):
        return self.p.get_device_count()

    def getDeviceName(self, deviceID):
        return self.p.get_device_info_by_index(deviceID)["name"]

    def isInputDevice(self, deviceID):
        return int(self.p.get_device_info_by_index(deviceID)["maxInputChannels"]) > 0

    def getAPIName(self, deviceID):
        return self.p.get_host_api_info_by_index(self.p.get_device_info_by_index(deviceID)["hostApi"])["name"]

    def setToDefault(self):
        self.devices = [None]

    def setToDevices(self, devices):
        self.devices = devices

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False

    def destroy(self):
        self.p.terminate()
```